"Cheapest" question will get out of date...
This question is asking for the cheapest of a particular service. Not only will answers vary by location, they will also get outdated reasonably quickly.
We could perhaps change it to ask for a link to a site that maintains such information on an ongoing basis?

I agree, it's localized in multiple ways. If we go by the StackExchange standard it should probably be closed.

The discussed question was closed in Nov 2012.
